# When using Mockito.verify(), instead of just checking if the function is called on the mocked object, method from real object is being called

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, mockito

I am writing my first Unit test for a view model. I am referring the GithubBrowserArchitectureComponents sample. I am testing whether executing a function which sets value for a live data, invokes a function called in switch map for that live data from repository class. For this, I am using Mocktio.verify function, in this function I pass a parameter that is a mocked object for Repository class and verify if getPosts method is invoked. But I found that instead of just checking invocation it actually calls the method. Whereas the one in the sample does not

I am using Dagger 2 as well, so I suspected the repository is injected instead of being mocked and thus as shown in the sample, I have changed the testInstrumentationRunner to a custom one which uses a different application class i.e. TestApp

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class PostViewModelTest {
    private val testContext = TestCoroutineContext()

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @get:Rule
    val coroutinesDispatcherRule = ViewModelScopeMainDispatcherRule(testContext)

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private var repository = mock(PostRepository::class.java)
    private var appExecutor = mock(AppExecutors::class.java)
    private var postDao = mock(PostDao::class.java)

    private val postViewModel = PostViewModel(postDao, repository, appExecutor)


    @Test
    fun fetchWhenObserved(){
        postViewModel.showPosts("a", "b")
        postViewModel.posts.observeForever(mock())
        verify(repository).getPosts("a", "b")
    }

}
```

build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 3
        versionName "3.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.example.test.util.MyTestRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
```

MyTestRunner

```
/**
 * Custom runner to disable dependency injection.
 */
open class MyTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {
    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader, className: String, context: Context): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, TestApp::class.java.name, context)
    }
}
```

PostViewModel

```
class PostViewModel @Inject
constructor(var postDao: PostDao,
            var repository: PostRepository,
            var appExecutors: AppExecutors
): ViewModel(){
    private val showPosts = MutableLiveData<Pair<String, String>>()

  // Get Post Live Data
    var posts: LiveData<PagedList<Post>> = Transformations.switchMap(showPosts) { groupIdToUserId ->
        repository.getPosts(groupIdToUserId.first, groupIdToUserId.second)
    }

fun showPosts(groupId: String, userId: String) {
        showPosts.value = groupId to userId
}
}
```

Repository

```
open class PostRepository @Inject constructor(
    private var db: AppDatabase,
    private var postDao: PostDao,
    private var appExecutors: AppExecutors,
    private var apiService: ApiService,
    private var user: User
) {
fun getPosts(groupId: String, userId: String): LiveData<PagedList<Post>> {
        val factory = postDao.allPosts(groupId)
        factory.create()
        val boundaryCallback = PostBoundaryCallback(groupId, userId, postDao, apiService,  appExecutors)
        return LivePagedListBuilder(factory, 10)
            .setBoundaryCallback(boundaryCallback)
            .setFetchExecutor(appExecutors.diskIO())
            .build()
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to test here? Could you show your viewmodel & repository so we get full context.

Comment: I am trying to test if the showPosts Method is working as expected. I have added Post ViewModel and Repository

Answer (score 0):

A unit test is testing a single unit of code, some of your test is testing the wiring between different classes. This is ok, but its an integration test rather than a unit test.

To test units, you want to test the inputs and outputs. For example the input params of a method and the output return value.

Therefore for your ViewModel you would only want to test that calling your `showPosts` method assigns the passed input to the LiveData. You would need to mock the LiveData and verify the method has been called with your input.

Separately you should test your repository by passing in input and verifying that the returned LiveData is what you expect. (Personally I would not return LiveData from the repository, I would return your value and wrap it in a LiveData inside the viewmodel but that is your choice).

Once you have those two tests you have tested both the units. If you then want to create an integration test (testing that the livedata updates when your repository runs its code and the system observes the results) then there is less benefit in doing so, as you are testing the system code and not your own. It would also be messier (as you are finding out) and more brittle to changes.

Hope that puts you in the right direction, even if its not directly a coding answer. :)

Comment: I appreciate your help. But you can see that I am not at all testing an integration. It is  a unit test to verify that the observer is working correctly which is in the same class.

The method verify is not supposed to call the repository. Its main purpose is to test whether on changing the value of the live data show post the switch map is triggered, which means testing the switchmap.

My method to check that it is triggered or not is also correct as verify method does not calls an actual method instead just checks whether the method was invoked on a mock

Comment: This is the link to the Google's example for conducting unit test for a ViewModel:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/test/java/com/android/example/github/ui/repo/RepoViewModelTest.kt

When I run it, it never calls method of actual instance instead just verifies and pass/fails the test

Comment: right, well if its not working I would remove as much code as possible to try and reproduce your problem with the smallest codebase, that way you know what is being used and what isn't https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example